# Color hex-value field is missed

Tags: adobe-photoshop, colors

Recently I have installed Photoshop CC. Now I have this color picker window. There is no hex field for color.

Where I can find editable field with hex value?

[image: color picker window]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was 32 bit/channel accidentally set. After 8 bit/channel missed fields appeared.

Comment: If anyone else is wondering I don't think you can set this on a global scale; I had to go into: Image / Mode - and then change it to 8-bit; I selected to not merge as merging seemed to change the colors.

Answer (score 1):

The R, G, and B colors at the bottom are the decimal (0-255) values, just convert them to hex (00-FF).

Comment: I do not want to convert every color via this way. I used to use old version of PS like [this one](http://pe-images.s3.amazonaws.com/type/effects/gel/photoshop-color-picker.jpg). May be it could be customized?